# Scala type equality and path-dependent types

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to express a constraint like:

`in a method def run[A, B](...), B must be equal to A#SomeInner`

Here is my example code:

```
trait Wrapper {
  type Implementation
  implicit val instance: Data[Implementation]
}

trait Data[A] {
  def create : A
}

object DataInstances {
  implicit object IntData extends Data[Int] { def create = 0}
  implicit object StringData extends Data[String] { def create = "<empty>"}
  implicit object FloatData extends Data[Float] { def create = 0.5F}
}


import DataInstances._

object IntWrapper extends Wrapper { type Implementation = Int; implicit val instance = IntData }
object StringWrapper extends Wrapper { type Implementation = String; implicit val instance = StringData}
object FloatWrapper extends Wrapper { type Implementation = Float; implicit val instance = FloatData}



object Test extends App {

  def run[W <: Wrapper, D](wrapper: W)(implicit data: Data[D], ev: D =:= W#Implementation) : D = {
    data.create
  }

  run(StringWrapper)
}
```

and here I get a compilation error:

```
Error:(31, 6) ambiguous implicit values:
              both object IntData in object DataInstances of type DataInstances.IntData.type
              and object StringData in object DataInstances of type DataInstances.StringData.type
              match expected type Data[D]
              run(StringWrapper)
                ^
```

Can you explain me why the compiler finds it ambiguous?
From what I can tell (and what I tried to express) is that when I pass `StringWrapper` then, according to type equality evidence the only possible value for `D` would be `String` and therefore the only possible value for `data` would be `StringData`.

But obviously the compiler doesn't think so :)

And what would be the way to express this constraint properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason to introduce type D in method run. Without it method signature looks simpler and successfully compiles

```
def run[W <: Wrapper](wrapper: W)(implicit data: Data[W#Implementation]) : W#Implementation = {
     data.create
}
```

+++

btw, if you change order of implicits in your original method it will compile too, looks like 'ev' help to "type-bound" implicit resolution for data

```
  def run[W <: Wrapper, D](wrapper: W)(implicit ev: D =:= W#Implementation, data: Data[D]) : D = {
    data.create
  }
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot! I was stupid, I even do #1 in another place :) As for the second, yes, seems that order matters... Thanks again!